# Angular 2 inner html is not working for html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular2-template, angular2-forms, innerhtml

I have an array with displayName in it contains html tag:

```
this.topicsList = [
{id: "173", name: "Discussion1", displayName: "Discussion1", status: 1},
{id: "174", name: "discussion123", displayName: "discussion123", status: 1},
{id: "192", name: "erer", displayName: "erer", status: 1},
{id: "184", name: "Hussa Test", displayName: "Hussa Test", status: 1},
{id: "194", name: "Ratheesh^TM^", displayName: "Ratheesh<sup> TM </sup>", status: 1},
{id: "181", name: "test test", displayName: "test test", status: 1},
{id: "189", name: "test topic", displayName: "test topic", status: 1},
{id: "195", name: "test^TM^tdtest", displayName: "test<sup> TM </sup>tdtest", status: 1},
{id: "190", name: "topic test", displayName: "topic test", status: 1},
{id: "193", name: "yu", displayName: "yu", status: 1}
]
```

I want to display, display name as super scripted form while listing and remove the html tag, but even though I use [innerHtml] display name list as it in the array(not functioning html tags) Please help me to find a solution.

```
<select class="form-control select-topic" id="select-topic-id"  formControlName="topic" [ngModel]="topicSelected || ''"   (ngModelChange)="topicSelected = $event">
  <option value="">Select Topic</option>
  <option *ngFor="let topic of topicsList" value="{{topic.id}}">{{topic.displayName}}</option>
</select>
```

I added [innerHtml] also. But doesn't solved my issue.

```
<select class="form-control select-topic" id="select-topic-id"  formControlName="topic" [ngModel]="topicSelected || ''" (ngModelChange)="topicSelected = $event">
  <option value="">Select Topic</option>
  <option *ngFor="let topic of topicsList" value="{{topic.id}}"><div  [innerHtml]="topic.displayName"></div></option>
</select>
```

Comment: In the stackblitz I've created it is working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3ayyw can you please explain us more details of the issue you are facing

Comment: The correct way is using [innerHtml], according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding . What exactly means "But doesn't solved my issue"?

Comment: And one suggestion, don't use `formControlName and [ngModel]` at the same time, `formControlName` is for reactive forms where as `[ngModel]` for template driven forms

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. try with this one <div [innerHTML]="topic.displayName">.

Comment: I tried this also. No use.

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML tag "select", [innerHTML] is not working, so the displayName is not superscripted. Instead of "Select" tag use "ul" for the dropdown.

[Note: Refer Bootstrap dropdown for style the dropdown.]

```
    <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- toggle="dropdown"><label>Select Manager</label>
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li *ngFor="let topic of topicsList" [innerHTML]="topic.displayName"> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: But this wont suite my style. :(